# mallocing array of structs creates too small of an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm a little new to structs in C and I'm having a problem with creating an array to store them. As the title says when I try to malloc out an array of structs my array ends up being too small by quite a large margin.

Here is my struct:

```
struct Points
{
  char file_letter;
  char *operation;
  int cycle_time;
};
```

And here is how I'm trying to create the array:

```
struct Points *meta_data;
meta_data = malloc(number_of_delims * sizeof(struct Points));
```

number_of_delims is an int representing the number of Points I'm trying to create and therefore the number of elements in my array.

With number_of_delims being 64 I get an array size of about 8.

Note: this is more or less a project for school and I can't use typedef when declaring my struct as the prof. wants each struct explicitly declared as one each time it is used. This may actually be the source of my problem but we'll see!

Comment: `With number_of_delims being 64 I get an array size of about 8.` How do you know this?

Comment: How do you know the array size is about 8?

Comment: `sizeof(meta_data)` might be 8... but that would be the size of the pointer, not the size of the array.

Comment: I suspect your confusing the size of the pointer `meta_data` with what the meta_data points to.

Comment: I've been populating my array iteratively and it always segfaults at the 8 mark, so I must be mistaking how I'm allocating the memory or populating my array

Comment: Where do you malloc the memory for `operation`? A short complete example of the crash would help debug this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> struct Points *meta_data;
> ```

At this point we have a declaration of an object, `meta_data` that has type `struct Points *`... and `struct Points *`, being a pointer type, typically requires 8 bytes on common implementations. This is observable through the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Points;
int main(void) {
    struct Points *meta_data;
    printf("sizeof meta_data: %zu\n", sizeof meta_data);
}
```

Remember, the `sizeof` operator evaluates the size of the *type* of the expression, which in this case is a *pointer*. Pointers don't carry size information about the arrays they point into. You need to keep that (i.e. preferably by pairing `number_of_delims` with `meta_data`, if you require both values later on).

---

> With number_of_delims being 64 I get an array size of about 8.

No. You get an array size of *exactly* 64, as you've expected. Your pointer doesn't automatically carry that size information around with it (because you're expected to), so there is no portable way to come to the conclusion that your allocation can store 64 elements. The only way you could come to this conclusion is *erroneously* (i.e. by attempting to use `sizeof`, which as I've explained doesn't work as you expect).

---

As an exercise, what happens if you declare a pointer to an array of 64 `struct Points`, like so?

```
struct Points (*foo)[64] = NULL;
```

For a start, how many elements can `NULL` contain? What is `sizeof foo` and `sizeof *foo`? Do you see what I mean when I say `sizeof` evaluates the size of the *type* of an expression?

Comment: I think I understand the issue relating to sizeof being misused to evaluate the size of my array. I think my problem may come down to happy coincidence since populating my array iteratively segfaults at the 8th iteration. I guess my question then is does the code I have at least provided look correct and should I be looking for my issue elsewhere?

Comment: @AcuteAvocado You should try reading [this FAQ page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), among the others, before you post here again... It's good manners to familiarise yourself with the requirements of a community before asking them for help, and just might show you how to debug these issues yourself. P.S. Have you heard of valgrind?

Comment: I apologize for the noobish nature of my post I've been stuck on this program for some time now and I tried to keep my questions simple and direct. I may have forsaken some etiquette though in my attempt at that. I do appreciate you taking the time to help me understand what I'm doing a bit more! I have not heard of valgrind, though from a quick search it looks like a debugger? I'm using GDB currently but it's lead me down some dead ends from what I can see. Maybe a second opinion might be worth it. Apologies again for how I conducted myself.

Comment: Valgrind will tell you if and where you're overflowing arrays or double-freeing, among other memory-related errors which are likely to cause the symptoms you've described (the segfault).

Comment: Thanks I will look into it!

Comment: @AcuteAvocado Don't worry, these things take time and practice. Just keep at it.